# Writing Solidity tests for array length & contents (chai)

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

## tdlr; solution

I had to `await` both of the values used in my assertions. For grabbing the length of the array, I needed to add a new method to my contract, as shown here. The reason for this is in the accepted answer.

```
function getPeopleSize() public view returns (uint256) {
     return people.length;
}
```

And here is the passing `it` block:

```
it("should add a person and their favorite number", async () => {
  const expectedValue = "11";
  const expectedName = "John";
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson(
    expectedName,
    expectedValue
  );
  transactionResponse.wait(6);

  const johnValue = await simpleStorage.nameToFavoriteNumber(expectedName);
  const peopleSize = await simpleStorage.getPeopleSize();

  assert.equal(peopleSize, 1);
  assert.equal(johnValue, expectedValue);
});
```

---

I have a function `addPerson`, which stores a new name and favorite number:

```
function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
}
```

`people` is an array and `favoriteNumber` is a uint256. Both are public data types.

```
uint256 favoriteNumber;

struct People {
  uint256 favoriteNumber;
  string name;
}

People[] public people;

mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;
```

In my deployed Remix contract, I'm able to call, for example, `nameToFavoriteNumber` with the string of the user I've added, and the supplied number is returned as expected. However, I'm unsure how to write a test for the `addPerson` function, to ensure that the name and favorite number are indeed getting stored.

Here's what I've tried. The length of `people` is printing zero and the mapper prints `undefined`. I'm expecting it to pass with length equal to 1 and the mapper equal to 11. One final note is that my other tests are passing, so I'm certain that the `simpleStorage` contract deployed properly in my testing environment.

```
it("should add a person and their favorite number", async () => {
    const expectedValue = "11";
    const expectedName = "John";
    const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson(
      expectedName,
      expectedValue
    );
    transactionResponse.wait(6);

    const people = simpleStorage.people;

    const johnValue = simpleStorage.nameToFavoriteNumber[expectedName];

    assert.equal(people.length, 1);         // prints 0
    assert.equal(johnValue, expectedValue); // prints undefined
});
```

Comment: Do you use truffle? checkout the way to call functions in here: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript/
You also missing a lot of "await"

Comment: Consider switching to [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and you will have a much easier life writing tests for your smart contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I think is missing the keyword **await** to wait for the contract method promise to be resolved and the **()** in the end of each method.

Check to see if it helps.

```
it("should add a person and their favorite number", async () => {
    const expectedValue = "11";
    const expectedName = "John";
    const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson(
      expectedName,
      expectedValue
    );

    // added await
    await transactionResponse.wait(6);

    // added await    
    // added () in the end (its a method)    
    // solidity retrieves only the value inside the position you pass. You must create a getPeopleSize method inside the contract to retrieve all length.
    const people = await simpleStorage.people(some index);

    // added await    
    // added () in the end (its a method)    
    const johnValue = await simpleStorage.nameToFavoriteNumber(expectedName);

    assert.equal(people.length, 1);
    assert.equal(johnValue, expectedValue);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Adding the await gets the  `johnValue` assertion to pass. However, the assertion for array length is still failing. It's telling me `people` is missing an argument? `Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)`

Comment: Also, the `toString()` on the mapping assertion was not needed.

Comment: oh that's correct, cuz you need to pass the index of the array to get it's value (people). So just keep in mind that my answer was to let you able to get values from the contract, now you can go and make the refinements

Comment: I solved my issue creating a method to return the size of the array. I'm not sure why it's needed, but the test is passing.

Comment: Cool, that was what I was about to say but forget in my last comment

Comment: But why would another method be needed just to return the length of a public array?

Comment: it's cuz solidity don't return the full array, but the value on a specific position of it's array. So creating inside the contract the method to return the length you will be fine. Will update my answer if you don't mind considering it as the chosen one, I'll appreciate.

Comment: Sure thing. Please update the answer and I'll update my question with the added `getPeopleSize()` method that fixed my other test.

Comment: Sure, just updated! lfg!